# While using ModelMapper, how do I specify custom mappings for specific properties on my source class?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, modelmapper

To be specific, I want to convert a String in my Source class (`PurchaseOrderFilterViewModel`) to an `org.joda.time.LocalDate` in my Destination class (`PurchaseOrderFilter`).

I tried using `PropertyMap<Source, Destination>` in accordance with the [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/) but it doesn't work. The dates in the Destination class are always assigned to the current date which is the default LocalDate when null is passed in as the constructor parameter.

```
    PurchaseOrderFilterViewModel purchaseOrderFilterViewModel1 = new PurchaseOrderFilterViewModel();
    purchaseOrderFilterViewModel.setStartReceiptDate("2015-04-15");
    purchaseOrderFilterViewModel.setEndReceiptDate("2015-04-17");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    modelMapper.createTypeMap(PurchaseOrderFilterViewModel.class, PurchaseOrderFilter.class);
    modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<PurchaseOrderFilterViewModel, PurchaseOrderFilter>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
            map().setStartReceiptDate(new LocalDate(source.getStartReceiptDate()));
            map().setEndReceiptDate(new LocalDate(source.getEndReceiptDate()));
        }
    });

    PurchaseOrderFilter purchaseOrderFilter = modelMapper.map(purchaseOrderFilterViewModel, PurchaseOrderFilter.class);
```

Comment: Can you please add the specific Exception in your answer as well

Comment: I've edited the question and the underlying issue is undesirable behavior, not an exception. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in configure, you are using DSL to define mapping. It's not the code that is run when modelmapper does mapping.

In other words your configuration now instructs to map `setStart/EndReceptionDate` as `new LocalDate(null)`, because `source.getStart/EndReceiptDate()` returns `null` when you define the configuration.

You should use a [Converter](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#converters).